# Twitter API : how to know if I am following someone

Tags: twitter, tweepy

To follow someone I use `api.create_friendship(user_id)` and this method call is in a try statement. So I was thinking it will raise an error if I was already following the user but it doesn’t.
This because `.create_friendship(user_id)`...
[image: explanation]
Ok I can’t detect it with an error handler so how ?! 
Knowing that `user[« following »]` is deprecated by the twitter API doc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friendships-show) there is an API call to see if you are following someone.

Use `friendships/show` to determine if you are already following a user.